# Vote total tooltip shows magnitude superfluously

Tags: feature-request, vote-count

Currently, the tooltip for split vote totals shows something akin to `+1 up / -1 down`.

The double-negative here is bugging me (and the double-positive too, actually). I feel it should say either `1 up / 1 down` or `+1 / -1`.

Comment: Good point, +1 up

Comment: It gets ugly if there are no downvotes. `+1 / 0 == +Inf`?

Comment: This really bugs me also.  I like your suggestions, and if either are zero then just ignore completely (e.g. `7 up`).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you are looking at.

It looks like you want it to already for me:

[image]

Comment: It's in the tooltip.

Comment: I'm looking at the tooltip that appears on rollover.

Comment: A marvelously pedantic observation if I ever saw one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ha, yes i see it now. wow that is weird.